# Evaluate a shell command in YAML file to create dynamic values in YAML

Tags: yaml, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a YAML file in which I want to evaluate few values dynamicallu. Like for the following YAML:

```
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets: ["10.10.10.10:3001"]
```

In the above YAML, I want to keep the ***IP address part of the targets section*** as dynamic, so that it can pick up the hostname, something like:

```
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets: ["$(hostname):3001"]
```

Is it possible? What is the right syntax for that?